# How to get the right substring after split?

Tags: java

I have a string like this:`[name ;24, name;23, name;22]`. How can i split this string to obtain only the numbers after";"?

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = "[name ;24, name;23, name;22]";
String couples[] = s.replace("]", "").split(",");
int ages[] = new int[couples.length];
for (int i=0; i< couples.length; i++)
    ages[i] = Integer.parseInt(couples[i].split(";")[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Your input looks like this.
String s = "[name ;24, name;23, name;22]";

String[] numberStrings = s
    // First get rid of the known prefix and suffix
    .substring("[name ;".length(), s.length - "]".length())
    // Then split on the repeated portion that occurs between numbers.
    .split(", name;");
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another method

```
String str = "name ;24, name;23, name;22";
int p = 0;
while ((p  = str.indexOf(";", p + 1))  > -1) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(p+1).split("[^0-9]")[0]);
}
```